# Ios multi activity project

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS.  How to assign the UIViewController to each view?

Comment: your question is not very clear, please re phrase your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new ViewController with the option to add a xib file automatically, the view and the view controller will be linked.

Otherwise, if you created the xib file independently from the view controller, you have to define the custom class of the view controller with the right/inspector panel that the "File's Owner"

Answer (score 0):

Guess you're coming from the Android world :). In iOS, Activities can be related to `UIViewController`.

Comment: so how can i assign a UIViewController to each view?

Comment: an UIViewController has, by default, a UIView. To link a view controller to a particular view, you have two solutions. Using the GUI file called <something>.xib or by creating a view in the UIViewController function 'loadView'. Something like UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:<aFrame>]; self.view = aView; [aView release];